# AngularJS: The view doesn't update when a model has changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

everyone!

I have a problem with the view update when my model has changed.

Here is a simple example:

I have the service which returns an instance of object. This object is the source of data for my app.

I have directives with controllers which interacts with the service.

The problem is, as I say before, when a controller changes a data in the service, these changes doesn't appear in my view.

I tried to force a view update when updating my model by adding a $scope.$apply() in my controller code:

```
$scope.click = () => {
  $scope.$apply(function() { 
    TestService.inc();
  });
  console.log(TestService);
};
```

But this causes an error: 'Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress'. I suppose, because ng-click is already including $apply.

Here is my code below. What am I doing wrong?

```js
console.log('> load app.module.js');

class Test {
  constructor(n = 0) {
   console.log('> create a Test class instance');
    this.counter = n;
  }
  inc() {
    this.counter++;
  }
}

angular
  .module('app', [])
  .service('TestService', function() {
    console.log('> create the TestService');
    return new Test(42);
  })
  .directive('myTestDirective', [
    function() {
     console.log('> create the myTestDirective');
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: 'counter: {{counter}} <button ng-click=click($event)>count</button>',
        controller: ['$scope', 'TestService',
          function($scope, TestService) {
          console.log('> initialise the directive\'s controller');
            $scope.counter = TestService.counter;
            $scope.click = () => {
              TestService.inc();
              console.log(TestService);
            };
          }
        ],
      };
    }
  ])
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app='app'>
  <my-test-directive>...</my-test-directive>
  <my-test-directive>...</my-test-directive>
</body>
```

Comment: Try  $scope.$digest() instead of  $scope.$apply()

Comment: Nischal -- There is same error.